# Why is std::cin outputting whatever is given to it?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdin

I've been working on learning C++, and obviously one of the first steps is learning to get input and output. However, I've encountered an issue where, when I call std::cin and use it to put the returned information into a variable, it then prints out whatever was given to it, AS WELL as whatever was printed out on the same line. So the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std::endl;
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    cout << "Testing this ";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

returns:

```
C:\Users\...\LearnCpp.exe
Hello World
Testing this5
Testing this 5
5
Process finished with exit code 0
```

It's also noteworthy that when I entered 5, it is directly next to this, as in "this5", even though there should be a space there. Then, once I hit enter, it prints it out as it should look, "this 5".

I've tried it without the space and it does the same, and I've tried it with a newline after "Testing this ", and it prints 5 twice:

```
C:\Users\...\LearnCpp.exe
Hello World
Testing this
5
5
5
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've scoured the internet looking for why, and I'm at my wits end. I'm using CLion with MinGW and CMake. My CMakeLists.txt file looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.2)
project (LearnCpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(LearnCpp ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, or what might be wrong with my setup?

Comment: I just tried your code (Visual Studio 2013) and it works exactly as expected, without the extra output you have described. I get a space after "Testing this ", and a number I enter there is only printed once after I press Enter.

Comment: I think the issue is somewhere in my setup. I don't have any idea where that might be though. Could it be something with CMake?

Comment: It's unlikely to be CMake. But you could compile your code without using CMake to check. It's more likely to be something in the MinGW runtime support, although it would surprise me if something that basic is in fact broken.

Comment: I believe it is. When I compile outside of CLion, and indeed even when I just debug it step by step, it works as predicted. I guess it only happens during runtime. I didn't even consider this as a possibility. Where can I ask more about this?

Comment: Tried your code under Gcc 4.8 under Linux Mint - Debian, and it works fine.

Comment: Try putting a `<< endl;` after `cout << "Testing this ";`

Comment: You should look up flushing the buffer. Sometimes weird stuff happens randomly. Something like:

cin.ignore( cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() );
cin.clear();

Comment: @JClark4321: *Sometimes weird stuff happens randomly.* <- That's not a very good way to approach programming. Everything happens for a reason, it's just that the reason might be unexpected.